# can we pass array/list to template content blocks in django? python

Tags: python, django, list, include

I know we can pass variables to content blocks but are we able to pass list?

I know we can pass variables in this way

```
{% include "partials/pickUp-Order-Form.html" with form="form" %}
```

I tried passing list like this

```
{% include "partials/pickUp-Order-Form.html" with form=["list", "test"] %}
```

this wouldn't work though.  I searched up and there doesn't seem to have such thing in documentations.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your html template that you want to include? The  `pickUp-Order-Form.html` from your code snippet (`{% include "partials/pickUp-Order-Form.html" %}`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a list in a variable or object, you can do it like this:

```
{% include "partials/pickUp-Order-Form.html" with form="list test".split %}
```

or you can create the variable first and then pass it to the include tag:

```
{% with "list test" as list %}
    {% include "partials/pickUp-Order-Form.html" with form=list.split %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Does this work? I got error trying the first one -
Could not parse the remainder: '.split'

Answer (score -2):

The `include` django template tag can be used for loading and rendering HTML templates where the context/data that was passed to the original template gets passed.

You can find documentation about this functionality in the [built-ins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/) section.

So if you would like to include a template, of which original view that renders the template has the following context dict: `{'word': 'Bird', 'power_level': 9001}` you can render it inside another template with: `{% include "word_template.html" with word="Not a Bird" power_level="470" %}`, which will in turn change the values to the desired ones.

To answer the question:

### It should work

Taking into consideration you `include` a template which will not use the `list` type as something else.